# How to determine encoding of Clipboard contents

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, clipboard

I have a 3rd party application from which I need to copy texts and paste it into visual studio. However, when I copy the text like *vysved****č****enie* and paste into Visual Studio text editor, I get *vysved****è****enie*.

I bet it's due to the other program putting non-unicode encoded text into clipboard. So I made a program to periodically check clipboard and convert the text into unicode like this:

```
var originalText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
Clipboard.SetText(originalText, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
```

This works fine, but the problem is how do I determine I already have a unicode-encoded text in the clipboard so that I don't try to convert it again?

I thought that `Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText)` would work, but this always returned true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Clipboard.GetDataObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdataobject.aspx).

Then you can call [`GetFormats()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idataobject.aspx) on the `IDataObject` returned.

Comment: Well, that still returns `UnicodeText` among the formats, but also `OEMText` and `Locale` which I can use to what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also note:  Note from MSDN documentation:
The Clipboard class can only be used in threads set to single thread apartment (STA) mode. To use this class, ensure that your Main method is marked with the STAThreadAttribute attribute.